# Return only true predicates in Java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following method:

```
public boolean isMsgOk(String msg) {...}
```

I want to call this method here:

```
public String[] returnOkMessages(String... msgs) {
    return Arrays
        .asList(messagessgs)
        .stream(message->isMsgOk(message))
        .anyMatch() ???;
}
```

I want to return a `List` of `String`s for which the `isMsgOk` method returns `true`.
How can I collect them?

Comment: Note `anyMatch` returns a `boolean`, `firstMatch` returns a `String` and `toArray` returns a `String[]`

Comment: I believe it's a duplicate. There is a lot of questions about the `filter`+`collect` pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `filter` and then `collect` to a `List`:

```
return Arrays.asList(messagessgs)
             .stream()
             .filter(message->isMsgOk(message))
             .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

or:

```
return Arrays.stream(messagessgs)
             .filter(this::isMsgOk)
             .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

EDIT:

If the output should be an array, use:

```
return Arrays.stream(messagessgs)
             .filter(this::isMsgOk)
             .toArray(String[]::new)
```

Comment: It's not working because of the "Collectors.toList()".
It says: "toList( ) in Collectors cannot be applied"

Comment: @Twi I noticed that the return type of your method is an array, not a List, so perhaps you should use `.toArray(String[]::new)` instead of `.collect()`.

Comment: I changed the return type to ArrayList<String> but the Collectors.toList() still not working.

Comment: @Twi What error do you see?

Comment: @Twi change the return type to `List<String>`

Comment: Oh yes, right. I am not really awake, sorry!

Answer (score 4):

Collect them to a `List` (you could also use a method reference instead of a lambda)

```
 .filter(this::isMsgOk)
 .toArray(String[]::new);
```